# How to extends ArrayAdapter to print Parsed JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

I have tried and read so many answers but can't able to figure out how to properly code...

NewsAdapter.java

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NEWSADAPTER";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> items){
        super(activity, R.layout.news_feed, items);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "This is came from the world i know of" + items);
        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed, parent, false);
    }
}
```

news_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="@string/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the output of above code is ...

[image]

How to get items value and how to setText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NEWSADAPTER";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> items){

        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

       View v = convertView
        if(v == null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed, parent, false);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtTitle.setText(items.get(position));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public NewsAdapter` asking me to insert `super();` Shall I ?

Comment: then use super() which you are using before